Does the Clock affect the Skeleton Medallist?
Trying to get the drops from the Skeleton Medallist. The Castlevania Wiki currently says to use the Clock to slow it down enough so I can catch up to it.
But I've been trying that and the clock doesn't seem to affect it?
Or am I just not noticing it work?
